# Password policy with pam_tally2 and 6 ssh password prompts

Tags: password, pam

I'm trying to configure a password policy on an embedded Linux distro.

I want to have a 30 seconds cooldown after 3 failed login attempts.

Therefore, I added in the common-auth file the last line,

```
auth       required     pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=30 even_deny_root
```

To enforce it

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth       required     pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=30 even_deny_root
```

But when I try to run ssh and the login fails, this part of the password policy is never enforced. In fact, when trying to log in, 6 (and not 3) login prompts are showing, so I suppose there are other modules involved in the login that interfere with common-auth file

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @ljden Yes, I did but i forgot to upload the answer. I wrote the solving code in my previous job so I can't collect it

Comment: That's unfortunate! Thanks for getting back to me